# Bash GUI programming: No/incorrect Zenity return value in bash script

Tags: bash, variables, return-value, zenity

I am trying to use zenity to obtain input from a user in a bash script. (Zenity is a bash callable gui toolkit "thing")

Here is my attempt so far

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ true ]]
then
    # send a message to ask if data should be saved
    # do some form of copy to save the data
    zenity --question --title="Ramdisk Unmount" --timeout=0 --text="Save ramdisk contants to disk?" --ok-label="Yes" --cancel-label="No"
    rvar=$?
    #echo $rvar > /media/ramdisk/returnval
    if [[ $rvar == 0 ]]
    then
        DIR=$(zenity --file-selection --title="Ramdisk Unmount" --directory)
        CODE=$?
        echo $CODE
        echo $DIR
        case $CODE in
            0)
                echo "dir=$DIR"
                ;;
            1)
                echo "No directory selected"
                ;;
            -1)
                echo "An error occured"
                ;;
        esac
        echo $DIR
        echo $DIR > /media/ramdisk/dir
    else
        rm -rf /media/ramdisk/*
    fi    
    #umount /media/ramdisk
else
    false
fi
read -n1 -r -p "Press Enter to continue"
```

Note zenity version is `3.22.0`

The first few lines including the first zenity command appear to be working, although strangely when I tried

```
rvar=`zenity --question --title="Ramdisk Unmount" --timeout=0 --text="Save ramdisk contants to disk?" --ok-label="Yes" --cancel-label="No"`
```

this didn't appear to work, and

```
rvar=$(zenity --question --title="Ramdisk Unmount" --timeout=0 --text="Save ramdisk contants to disk?" --ok-label="Yes" --cancel-label="No")
```

also did not appear to work as expected. (In both cases `echo $rvar` printed a blank line.) I think this might be connected to the issue I am having at the moment, which is...

At the moment the bash script appears to terminate after the second zenity command. The path chosen in the zenity dialog is printed to (what I assume is) stdout, however nothing further happens, the script just quits and returns to the bash terminal.

No code is printed by `echo $CODE`.

Nothing is printed by `echo $DIR`.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: FYI, `[[ true ]]` behaves identically to `[[ false ]]` (as, not being empty, both strings are truthy). Consider `while true` or its idiomatic equivalent `while :; do` to avoid leaving readers with false implications about how booleans work in shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Two good questions - as to the second I don't know. It seems to work if I run the command directly in a bash terminal. As to the first, this is just a placeholder for the moment - I should remove this if statement, but I assume this isn't the cause of the problem?

Comment: Agreed; if I knew the cause of the problem, I'd be adding an answer rather than commenting. Don't have zenity available at hand to test, hence just kibitzing.

Comment: ...well, I installed zenity, and can confirm at least one of your observations -- `zenity --question` *doesn't* write anything to stdout, but rather specifies to its caller which boolean option was selected via exit status only.

Comment: `echo $CODE` printing *nothing*, btw, is a very good hint that `CODE=$?` didn't get run in your current context at all.

Comment: ...as another aside, `CODE=-1` will never happen; return value is an *unsigned* integer, and can never be negative.

Comment: Silly question here -- any chance you might be running your script with `bash -e` or other debugging options not given in the question?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point about the case statement - I think what I've done is accidentally create two copies of a script and I was editing the wrong one? Although I have no clue still why that one (the one I was execing) didn't work. Managed to fix the issue but creating a new document, writing all the commands again and saving it, deleting the other two.) I did this line by line testing each change. Nothing was different but it seemed to work. Possibly an encoding error or something?

Comment: DOS line endings will definitely break a lot of miscellaneous things -- that's why they're the first thing listed in the "Before asking about problematic code" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info. If you still have the broken script around, running `bash -x yourscript` to enable trace logging is useful -- you'll see the CRs in CRLF sequences rendered as `$'\r'`s

Answer (score 0):

When running `zenity --question`, the boolean response is indicated only via exit status; there's thus no reason to collect stdout.

The folllowing Works For Me(tm), with Zenity 3.30.0:

```
if zenity --question --title="Ramdisk Unmount" --text="Save ramdisk contents to disk?"; then
  if dir=$(zenity --file-selection --title="Ramdisk Unmount" --directory); then
    echo "User requested unmount of the ramdisk at $dir" >&2
  else
    echo "User initially requested unmount but did not select a directory" >&2
  fi
else
  echo "User did not request unmount, or zenity failed" >&2
fi
```